# Why does this code compile when pasted in but fail otherwise?

Tags: vba, vb6, specifications, vbe

A friend made me look at [this page](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?781595-VB6-Call-Functions-By-Pointer-(Universall-DLL-Calls)), and noticed a strange piece of code in the signature of one of the forum users.

**The code is a one-liner that goes as follows:**

```
On Local Error Resume Next: If Not Empty Is Nothing Then Do While Null: ReDim i(True To False) As Currency: Loop: Else Debug.Assert CCur(CLng(CInt(CBool(False Imp True Xor False Eqv True)))): Stop: On Local Error GoTo 0
```

**Scrolling removed:**

> On Local Error Resume Next: If Not Empty Is Nothing Then Do While Null: ReDim i(True To False) As Currency: Loop: Else Debug.Assert CCur(CLng(CInt(CBool(False Imp True Xor False Eqv True)))): Stop: On Local Error GoTo 0

Quite mind-blowingly, that code compiles (I didn't try to run it, but that's irrelevant) if you just paste it as-is (and then don't touch it again!) into a valid procedure-level scope.

**Some observations:**

- If instruction separators / colons are replaced with new lines, it no longer compiles
- `On Local Error` can be simplified to `On Error`
- The nested conversions aren't of any particular interest at first sight, but it turns out replacing that series of conversions and comparisons with a simple `Debug.Assert True` makes the code consistently compile, so *something* in there is messing up the compiler.
- If the code is pasted, it compiles; if it's modified in any way (even merely removing `Local`) after the VBE has validated the line, it stops compiling, and nothing seems to make VBA understand it anymore, unless the line is deleted and re-pasted.
- The latest [rubberduck](/questions/tagged/rubberduck) grammar/parser being closely modeled on the actual VBA specs, [it parses and resolves just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOWh2.png) (which honestly blows my mind)
- If the line is known to not compile, and then cut/re-pasted, it doesn't compile... but re-pasting it again from outside the VBE, it suddenly compiles.

**The question is**, how does this code manage to compile against the VB language specs? Is it a bug in the VB[6|A|E] implementation? In other words, *why/how does it work*?

I *think* it has something to do with the instruction separator (`:`) and the inline-if syntax - given there's no `End If` statement, the thing *is* a single line and not a block.

But then, what makes *that specific code* be Schrödinger's code? What is it that makes it both legal and illegal at the same time?

If the code gets correctly parsed by a parser generated using a formal grammar definition (ANTLR), then it must be a legal construct? Then why does it stop being legal when you merely go back to that line and hit ENTER?

Comment: I was about to correct it to Schrödinger before that pesky cat disappeared, **again**

Comment: does simplifying the nested conversions to True, leave the code in the same 2 states?

Comment: @ThunderFrame it... doesn't (when it says `Debug.Assert True` then you can edit it again, it stays compilable). seems the nested conversions *do* matter then.

Comment: Interesting in that if you type it out manually, it doesn't compile either.  Is it possible to have hidden control codes in the text?  That used to be possible long ago, but I don't think you can do that any more.

Comment: @PhillipXT but the invisible control characters wouldn't be tokenized by a formal grammar definition; the lexer would just throw an exception at them and refuse to pipe them into the ANTLR token stream... unless I'm missing something. Perhaps I should add an ANTLR tag...

Comment: Yeah, no control characters there anyway - if you type it out into Notepad and paste it into VB it works fine.

Comment: Maybe problem is in missing `End If` - it is required for multiple line `If ... Then ...` construct, but not on single line.

Comment: Can't repro this on VB6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With such a long line of code, it's hard to spot where the compile error creeps in, but there is a subtle difference that appears to be the VBE applying an autocorrect to the line as, or more likely after, it is parsed.

### This is the *original* line - As pasted from the clipboard

The line appears like this **until** you move the cursor to another line.
Notice the colon, in bold, **between the `Loop` and `Else` keywords** statement:

> On Local Error Resume Next: If Not Empty Is Nothing Then Do While Null: ReDim i(True To False) As Currency: **`Loop: Else`** Debug.Assert CCur(CLng(CInt(CBool(False Imp True Xor False Eqv True)))): Stop: On Local Error GoTo 0

### This is the line *after* you move the cursor to another line:

Notice the colon has been auto-removed by VBE. It seems like the VBE parser recognizes the statement, and then "optimizes" the "redundant" colon away.

> On Local Error Resume Next: If Not Empty Is Nothing Then Do While Null: ReDim i(True To False) As Currency: **`Loop Else`** Debug.Assert CCur(CLng(CInt(CBool(False Imp True Xor False Eqv True)))): Stop: On Local Error GoTo 0

If you *add back* the colon to a line that is in the invalid syntax state, then the autocorrect kicks in again, but your line returns to being valid, but *fragile* code.

So, it seems that VBE parses the line, identifies an optimization (the redundant colon), and then applies the fix, but VBE doesn't realize the optimized line has syntax problems.

But why does the line end up being fragile? There are lots of distracting and irrelevant keywords in the line, so let's reduce it drastically:

### Do While..Loop

> If we minimize the complexity of the line, to isolate the problem, we can simplify the line to:
>   `If True Then Do While True: Beep: Loop: Else`
>   Which, again, VBE autocorrects to a *fragile* line:
>   `If True Then Do While True: Beep: Loop Else`
>   But we can go even further and reduce the line to an illogically short line:
>   `If True Then Do: Loop: Else`
>   And VBE, once again, dutifully removes the colon to produce this line: (**DO NOT EXECUTE THIS LINE OR YOU WILL HANG EXCEL)**
>   `If True Then Do: Loop Else`

### While..Wend

> Repeating the line, but swapping out the `Do While Loop`, for the older `While Wend` syntax:
>   `If True Then While True: Beep: Wend: Else`
>   Again, VBE optimizes away the colon, to give:
>   `If True Then While True: Beep: Wend Else`
>   But now the line is not *fragile* anymore!

So, the While..Wend is the older construct, and the Do..Loop construct is newer (and more flexible), but it seems the VBE parser (and syntax optimizer) struggle with the Do..Loop construct.

Key point: Don't use `Do..Loop` in Single-Line `If` statements that include an `Else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would adventure to answer that the `Resume Next` is a key instruction here, since anything else invalid would skip to the next instruction.

Colons separate the commands as if they were new lines.

It is otherwise very inriguing indeed.