# Dynamically Create Range Late Binding VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, late-binding

trying to dynamically create ranges using this:

```
 ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(q + 1, z + 1)).Value2 = xaRR
```

this works in excel like a charm, but access vba keeps giving me issue. It doesnt like the cells part. The annoying thing is this doesnt give me any fuss

```
 ws.Cells(1,1).Value = blah blah blah
```

When I try this:

```
        Dim oXL As Object: Dim wb As Object: Dim ws As Object: Dim rNg As Object: Dim cl As Object
        Set wb = .Workbooks.Add
        Set ws = wb.Sheets
        Set rNg = ws.Range
        Set cl = rNg.Cells
        ws.rNg(cl(1, 1), cl(q + 1, z + 1)).Value2 = xaRR
```

it says that rNg doesnt support this property or method.

Can someone help me see the obvious issue?

Comment: Do you need to use late binding?

Comment: @Comintern Yes. Due to the environment, I cannot use specific excel library references. Late binding is a requirements unfortunately.

Comment: In Access, qualify the call to `Cells` with `ws.`

Comment: `.Range` needs parameters so use it like in the original first line. You can probably use early binding for easier debugging and remove the reference after.

Comment: shorter option is `cl.Resize(q + 1, z + 1).Value2 = xaRR` because cells is already a range starting from A1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original line is using an implicit reference to the Activesheet. In Excel, that works (but is a bug if you don't mean to use the Activesheet), but in Access it will be an error. Qualify the Cells call with the sheet reference, for an explicit call:

I assume `ws` is a `Worksheet` object and not a `Worksheets` object

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(q + 1, z + 1)).Value2 = xaRR
```

Or in your second example:

I've removed the Cells variable, and I've also substituted the `: Dim` instruction separators for commas. Instruction separators are evil.

Your `ws` variable is *all* sheets, so I've just grabbed the first one, but your implementation may need to vary.

```
Dim oXL As Object, wb As Object, ws As Object
Set wb = .Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(q + 1, z + 1)).Value2 = xaRR
```

Comment: apparently set rNg = ws.Range isnt a supported method or property either. I will keep trying things until i figure it out.

Comment: see my edit, you need to set `ws` to a *single* sheet, with `Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)` instead of `Set ws = wb.Sheets`

Comment: Ah. I had to do that and take out the rNg reference and it worked like a chamr. thanks

Comment: why are instruction separators evil? I am genuinely curious about this

Comment: @DougCoats - I this case they just add 4 unnecessary characters.  In most other cases they make code less readable.  Can you tell at a glance what this line outputs?  `If True Then: Debug.Print "foo": Debug.Print "bar"`

Comment: When reading code, I expect 1 statement per logical line, but instruction separators allow multiple statements per line. If the instruction separator is off to the right of the screen, or on a continued line, or adjacent to certain other characters, it can be hard to spot, and makes code hard to understand and debug. Furthermore, the VBE doesn't always preserve them, which can lead to badly compiled code like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147979/why-does-this-code-compile-when-pasted-in-but-fail-otherwise

Comment: @ThunderFrame Ah Ok that makes sense. I shall reframe from doing with variable declarations. Is it a sin to do something like this? Dim c as string: c = "this" ? As long as thats the only thing on the line?

Comment: @DougCoats Best practice is to just not use them at all. If you see a line starting with `Dim`, you know you can just skip reading it, but if you use instruction separators, you have to read the entire line, just to make sure you're not missing something important, like `Dim c As String: c = Now() : If Instr(1,c,"1") > 0 Then End Else : Do While True : Loop 'Your Code just terminated or hung the VBE`

Comment: @ThunderFrame fine geez. I thought with simple stuff using the same line for simple variable assignments was more readable. My opinion clearly differs from most. oh well.